# Density of the methane

Tags: density

I would like to know the density of the Methane with a temperature of 348.15 Kelvin because i guess it is not the same that we can find on Wikipedia. Someone know where can i find that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The density of a gas at any temperature can be approximated using the ideal gas equation and the molar mass of the gas. Methane is a good candidate for a close approximation since it is nonpolar and relatively spherical. It should not deviate from ideality exept under extreme circumstances.

Density is the ratio of mass to volume:

$$D=\dfrac{m}{V}$$

If we assume that we have one mole of methane, we can use its molar mass to determine the mass of that one mole.

We can use the ideal gas equation to determine the molar volume of our gas (or any gas) at a given temperature and pressure. I presume you want the density at 1 atm or 1 bar, or you would have mentioned the pressure. How can we rearrange the ideal gas equation to solve for volume?

$$PV=nRT$$

Now it is just a matter of plugging in values. I am not going to do that for you.